# Custom y axle using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have this bar chart that I need to customize the "y" axle to say Half and Full, it will have the bars going all the way up and one half way. I read about custom scale, but cant find anything on how to do what I am trying.

```
 options: {
      legend: { // remove the rectangle box from the legend
         labels: {
       boxWidth: 0,
     }
      },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
        display: true, // hides y axis labels
        //min: 25, // at 25 or half way to say Half
        //max: 50, // at 50 to say Full
        //stepSize: 1,
               }
             }]
        },
       layout: {
        padding: {
              // Any unspecified dimensions are assumed to be 0
              left: 50,
              bottom: 10
            }
           },
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you literally want your scale to say "Full" and "Half" instead of showing the numbers?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do! Have you done anything like it?

Comment: Yup, see my answer below.

Comment: If you provide your full chart.js config (including your data) then I can make you a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you are wanting is possible.  You just need to use the scale `ticks.callback` option.  Here is an example.

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      callback: function(value) {
        if (value === 25) {
          return "Half";
        } else if (value === 50) {
          return "Full";
        }
      }
    }
  ]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is options in chartJS that helps you to scale your Y Axis :

Here is an example :

```
   {
        scaleSteps: 3,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
    }
```

and this gives you :

[image]

So for the half step you use : scaleStepWidth: 0.5

Comment: I see, but what I am looking for is to have my half point to say "Half" and the top to say "Full".

Comment: In this case set the "yLabels" option

Comment: to do so you can see the source code of chartJS, you want find "yLabels"